# Apache httpd block spam urls?

Tags: apache, web-applications, webserver, load-balancing, httpd.conf

I am using Apache httpd. I enabled apache's `rewrite` module. I need to block few urls (referer spam). I have permission to edit `httpd.conf` file. Is below syntax correct to block multiple urls?

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} sample.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} somexxx.com [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but, I think that:

- the `.` in the `RewriteCond` needs to be escaped
- you need `OR` flags on all but the final `RewriteCond`
- the `L` flag on the `RewriteRule` helps performance
- if you use a capture group you'll also block subdomains

So, I think you'll want something like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (example\.com) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (sample\.com) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (somexxx\.com) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

</Directory>
```